# How can I create a Tensor from an Example object in Java?

Tags: java, tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

My use case:
I am trying to serve the models trained by python within our existing JVM service with libtensorflow_jni.

Now I am able to load the model by using `SavedModelBundle.load()`. But I find hard to feed the request into the model. As my user request is not simply a scalar matrix, but a map of features, like:

```
{'gender':1, 'age': 20, 'country': 100, other features ...}
```

By searching around the tensor flow tutorials, I see that [Example](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.3/tensorflow/core/example/example.proto) protocol buffers may fit here as it basically holds a list of features. But I am not sure how to convert it into a Java Tensor object.

If I create a Tensor directly with serialized Example object, TensorFlow runtime seems not happy with datatype. For example, it I do following,

```
Tensor inputTensor = Tensor.create(example.toByteArray());
s.runner().feed(inputTensorName, inputTensor).fetch(outputTensorName).run().get(0);
```

I will get an IllegalArgumentException:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expected serialized to be a vector, got shape: []
```

Could you guys shed some light how I can move forward from here in case you happens to know or have same use cases?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your error message, it appears that the problem is that your model is expecting a vector of string tensors (most likely corresponding to a batch of serialized `Example` protocol buffer messages, probably from [`tf.parse_example`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/parse_example)) but you're feeding it a scalar string tensor.

Unfortunately, till [issue #8531](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/8531) is resolved, the Java API doesn't have a way to create a `Tensor` of strings except for scalars. Once that issue is resolved, things will be easier.

In the mean time, you could work around this by constructing a TensorFlow "model" to convert your scalar string into a vector of size 1 :). That could be done with something like this:

```
// A TensorFlow "model" that reshapes a string scalar into a vector.
// Should be much prettier once https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/7149
// is resolved.
private static class Reshaper implements AutoCloseable {
  Reshaper() {
    this.graph = new Graph();
    this.session = new Session(graph);
    this.in =
        this.graph.opBuilder("Placeholder", "in")
            .setAttr("dtype", DataType.STRING)
            .build()
            .output(0);
    try (Tensor shape = Tensor.create(new int[] {1})) {
      Output vectorShape =
          this.graph.opBuilder("Const", "vector_shape")
              .setAttr("dtype", shape.dataType())
              .setAttr("value", shape)
              .build()
              .output(0);
      this.out =
          this.graph.opBuilder("Reshape", "out").addInput(in).addInput(vectorShape).build().output(0);
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void close() {
    this.session.close();
    this.graph.close();
  }

  public Tensor vector(Tensor input) {
    return this.session.runner().feed(this.in, input).fetch(this.out).run().get(0);
  }

  private final Graph graph;
  private final Session session;
  private final Output in;
  private final Output out;
}
```

With the above, you can convert your example proto tensor to a vector and feed it into the model you're interested in with something like this:

```
Tensor inputTensor = null;
try (Tensor scalar = Tensor.create(example.toByteArray())) {
  inputTensor = reshaper.vector(scalar);
}
s.runner().feed(inputTensorName, inputTensor).fetch(outputTensorName).run().get(0);
```

For full details, [see this example on github](https://github.com/asimshankar/java-tensorflow/tree/master/string_vector_workaround)

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you, this works great. Btw, do you know how I can read a vector of string out of a Tensor that is returned by Tensorflow. For example, if s.runner().fetch(outputTensorName).run().get(0) returns a Tensor of vector of String. In java I do not see an API to retrieve the value out of the Tensor.